# angular 5 local development for multiple domains

Tags: angular5

say i have two different domains for the production build of an angular 5 based project ".com" and ".africa".

Now let say i have different logos for both the domains or i just want to run different code blocks on based on if condition which checks the domain names.

So, now how do i check on my local development environment that if my code will run or not on the production server since the angular project always runs on localhost:4200 i have no idea if my code is going to work or not.

Due to some reasons i can't deploy production build for every code i write to check if it is working for both the domain names for not.

Comment: Don't you guys have a staging environment similar to the prod environment? It would be really nice if you do.

Comment: well we do have a staging environment but unfortunately there is only one domain i.e., ".com" for staging server